# How to add multiple validators markers in single check

Tags: karate

For example, I have to check *id*, it must be string and must be present. Below one is not working :
match response == """{ id: '#present' '#string'}"""

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with this, it should work. you don't need the triple quotes. do read the docs and examples carefully.

```
* match response == { id: '#string' }
```

Comment: No you are checking only for string, suppose if I want to check for #present also, how will you do this for id

Comment: read. the. docs. all markers imply mandatory unless you prefix with ##